# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/project_env/bin/pip'

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

First of all I am pretty new to setting up virtual env so I can run a Python rest api on it . :)

I installed the virtual env. in the `/var` folder of my Ubuntu server with
`sudo python3 -m venv project_env`.

After activating the environment I tried to install Flask with following command: `(project_env) mStege@homeserver:/var$ pip install Flask`

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/project_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itsdangerous-2.0.1.dist-info' Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

After some research I tried following command to install Flask: `pip3 install Flask --user`
Which give me this error:

```
ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
```

Has it something to do where I installed the virtual enviroment?
I didn't put it in my homedir because there is a project-related website in the `var` folder and I want everything in one place. Also, there will be some other dudes I will be working with and I thought that it is quite suboptimal when they have to go through my home folder.

Comment: Hi, welcome here. Do you really need to create a venv with the super user? If not, don't create your venv using sudo.

Comment: @BeChillerToo because I get  "Permission denied" if I try to create a venv  in /var without using sudo...

Comment: Why do you create a venv in /var/? You could use pipenv to manage the venv for you, or you can create a venv alongside your source code.

Comment: @BeChillerToo 
Where should I place it else when I am working on it with multiple guys? I looked up the description of /var and thought it would be the right spot to install  the venv for the restAPI so everybody has access to it without going through my homefolder...

Comment: You don't share your venv with other users. Each dev on the team has a virtual env, that comes from a requirements.txt (or Pipfile if you use Pipenv)

Comment: @BeChillerToo hmmm ok I see

Comment: Do you want me to write an answer so you can close your question?

Comment: If you have time it would be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create your virtual environment (venv) in `/var`.

My advice:

- Create your virtual environment alongside your source code, if you're using `pip`
- If you're using `pipenv`, let pipenv choose where to create the venv

Each one of your colleagues should have their own venv. You can syncronize your environments by using a `requirements.txt` (or a Pipfile) to specify which packages and versions are needed.